# How to solve the following differential equation.....?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following differential equation.....?

\begin{equation}
x^3\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3+y^2 (y^2-x^2)^{1/2}
\end{equation}

It is a homogeneous equation. So after substituting $y=vx$ I get

\begin{equation}
\frac{dv}{v^3 + v^2 (v^2 -1)^{1/2}-v}=\frac{dx}{x}
\end{equation}

and what next?

Answer (score 0):

Next is you have to integrate both sides.
$$\begin{equation}
\int\frac{dv}{v^3 + v^2 (v^2 -1)^{1/2}-v}=\int\frac{dx}{x}
\end{equation}$$

substitue $v=\sec u$

$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\tan\left(u\right)}{\sec\left(u\right)\sqrt{\sec^2\left(u\right)-1}+\sec^2\left(u\right)-1}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\tan\left(u\right)}{\sec\left(u\right)\tan\left(u\right)+\sec^2\left(u\right)-1}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\tan\left(u\right)}{\tan^2\left(u\right)+\sec\left(u\right)\tan\left(u\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\tan\left(u\right)+\sec\left(u\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
$${\displaystyle\int}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\cos\left(u\right)}}\cdot\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\dfrac{1}{\sin\left(u\right)+1}}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

substitute $w=\sin u+1$ thus $dw=\cos u du $
$$\int \frac{1}{w} dw$$

can you complete the solution from here

Answer (score 0):

To evalute the integral on the left side of  $$\int \begin{equation}
\frac{dv}{v^3 + v^2 (v^2 -1)^{1/2}-v}= \int\frac{dx}{x}
\end{equation}$$
You may let $v=\sec t$ and your integral simplifies to $$ \int \frac {\sec t \tan t dt}{\sec ^3 t + \sec ^2 t \tan t -\sec t}$$ which in turn simplifies to $$ \int \frac {\cos t dt}{\sin t +1}$$

You can finish the problem easily.